# Error C2248 in Fstream.h

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, fstream, ofstream

This is the error message I'm getting:

> error C2248:
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
>   : cannot access private member
>   declared in class
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'   C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\fstream

this is the line it says the error is

```
template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits> inline
    void swap(basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Left,
        basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Right)
    {   // swap _Left and _Right basic_ofstreams
    _Left.swap(_Right);
    }
```

this is the code where I access fstream

```
char* stringPointer =  (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(saveFileNameString).ToPointer();


ofstream sessionFile;
sessionFile.open(stringPointer, std::ios_base::in);
 Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(stringPointer));`
```

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not on Fstream.h but on your code.

Check if your not passing a private member variable of a class to ofstream or some other method.

Comment: I'm checking and I really don't see anything

Comment: got it!!!! you cannot pass an ofstream into a function directly `ofstream sessionFileOutput; sessionFileOutput.open(stringPointer);//, fstream::out); Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(stringPointer)); XMLExport* exportingX = new XMLExport(); exportingX->saveSessionLurch(saveFileNameString, &sessionFileOutput, );`

Answer (score 1):

I just run into that problem, and thanks to Luron's comment I figured it out.

I post the explanation in case someone would have the same problem:

There is no copy constructor for stream objects (ostream, istream and derivates), and passing one of these objects to a function will call the copy constructor and so will cause the error.